# Construir um Array com o intervalo de datas

Tags: javascript, node.js

Vou receber duas datas, Exemplo: 01/10/2017, 31/10/2017. Como posso criar um array com todos os dias entre essas datas.

```
Array = ["01/10/2017", "02/10/2017", "03/10/2017", ... ,"31/10/2017"]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A idéia aqui é acrescentar os dias à data usando `data.setDate`. Enquanto a data inicial for menor do que a final, irá sendo acrescentada e incluída no *array*. As duas funções extras são para manter as datas no formato brasileiro.

```js
let d1 = toDate("01/10/2017"),
    d2 = toDate("31/10/2017"),
    intervalos = [];

intervalos.push( toString(d1) );

while ( d1 < d2 ) {
  d1.setDate( d1.getDate() + 1 );
  intervalos.push( toString(d1) );
}

console.log(intervalos);

function toDate(texto) {
  let partes = texto.split('/');
  return new Date(partes[2], partes[1]-1, partes[0]);
}

function toString(date) {
  return ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + '/' +
    ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '/' +
    date.getFullYear();
}
```

Comment: Exatamente isto que eu precisava, estava com dificuldade de adicionar um dia quando mudava o mês, mas assim funcionou muito bem, Obrigado

Comment: De nada! Você pode marcar a resposta como aceita se lhe serviu @ErickZanetti